# Unable to remove M365 licenses assigned to user

Tags: azure, powershell, office365

How can I modify the below script to remove all assigned licenses from a user account?

Script Input: User Principal Name (UPN): User.Name@domain.com

```
function Remove-License {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$UserPrincipalName
    )
    
    process {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess([string]$UserPrincipalName, "Remove License")) {
            
            try { $user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId $UserPrincipalName -ErrorAction Stop }
            catch { Write-Host "Error no user $($UserPrincipalName) is found" -ForegroundColor Red }
            
            $SKUs = @($user.AssignedLicenses)
            if (!$SKUs) { Write-Verbose "No Licenses found for user $($UserPrincipalName), skipping license removal process..."; continue }
            
            $userLicenses = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.AssignedLicenses
            foreach ($SKU in $SKUs) {
                $userLicenses.RemoveLicenses += $SKU.SkuId
            }
            
            Write-Verbose "Removing license(s) $($userLicenses.RemoveLicenses -join ", ") "
            try {
                $paramSetAzureADUserLicense = @{
                    ObjectId         = $user.ObjectId
                    AssignedLicenses = $userLicenses
                    ErrorAction      = 'Stop'
                    Verbose          = $true
                }
                
                Set-AzureADUserLicense @paramSetAzureADUserLicense
            }
            catch {
                if ($_.Exception.ErrorContent.Message.Value -eq "User license is inherited from a group membership and it cannot be removed directly from the user.") {
                    Write-Verbose "At least one of the user's licenses is assigned via group-based licensing feature, use the Azure AD blade to remove it"
                    continue
                }
                else { $_ | Format-List * -Force; continue }
            }
            
        }
    }
}

Remove-License -UserPrincipalName 'First.Name@domain.com' -Verbose
```

Error: Does not throws any error even when showing the Verbose.

[image]

The license is still assigned to the user, nothing is changed.

Comment: The first catch does not exit the function if the user is not found, so it continues with a $null `$user` variable. The second catch is way too specific. Remove the `if(..)` and write out the `$_.Exception.Message` to see what went wrong

Comment: Hi, @Theo thanks for the update. the 1st Try/Catch seems to know or show the error when the user is not found, so I wonder what should it be looks like according to your suggestion?
Also, regarding the second Try/Catch, not sure how can I modify it to reflect what you've suggested?

Comment: In the first catch, simply write `throw` to throw the exception, or more gracefully perhaps, do a `Write-Warning` about the user not found and exit the function with `return`. For the second catch, I'd suggest commenting out what you have there now and instead just do a `Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message` so you can see what went wrong